# Wifi option not available in ubuntu14.04?

Tags: 14.04, wireless

I have newly installed Ubuntu14.04 in my laptop and after installation i saw no Wifi option is coming then i tried below things

```
sudo apt-get remove --purge bcmwl-kernel-source
sudo apt-get install linux-firmware-nonfree
sudo modprobe b43
sudo su
echo "b43" >> /etc/modules
```

As mentioned in [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0Tl98Hp-0ZA)

and here the screenshot of driver for Wifi

[image]

```
########## wireless info START ##########

Report from: 09 Nov 2015 21:35 IST +0530

Booted last: 09 Nov 2015 20:55 IST +0530

Script from: 27 Sep 2015 00:34 UTC +0000

##### release ###########################

Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 14.04.3 LTS
Release:    14.04
Codename:   trusty

##### kernel ############################

Linux 3.19.0-32-generic #37~14.04.1-Ubuntu SMP Thu Oct 22 09:41:40 UTC 2015 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

Parameters: ro, quiet, splash, vt.handoff=7

##### desktop ###########################

Ubuntu

##### lspci #############################

01:00.0 Ethernet controller [0200]: Broadcom Corporation NetLink BCM57785 Gigabit Ethernet PCIe [14e4:16b5] (rev 10)
    Subsystem: Acer Incorporated [ALI] Device [1025:0605]
    Kernel driver in use: tg3

02:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Broadcom Corporation BCM43227 802.11b/g/n [14e4:4358]
    Subsystem: Foxconn International, Inc. Device [105b:e040]
    Kernel driver in use: bcma-pci-bridge

##### lsusb #############################

Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 006 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 002 Device 002: ID 064e:d20c Suyin Corp. 
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 005 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 0bb4:0c02 HTC (High Tech Computer Corp.) Dream / ADP1 / G1 / Magic / Tattoo (Debug)
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub

##### PCMCIA card info ##################

##### rfkill ############################

0: acer-wireless: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no

##### lsmod #############################

wl                   6369280  0 
acer_wmi               20480  0 
sparse_keymap          16384  1 acer_wmi
b43                   421888  0 
bcma                   53248  1 b43
mac80211              708608  1 b43
ssb                    65536  1 b43
cfg80211              524288  3 wl,b43,mac80211
video                  20480  1 acer_wmi
wmi                    20480  1 acer_wmi

##### interfaces ########################

auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

##### ifconfig ##########################

eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr <MAC 'eth0' [IF]>  
          inet addr:192.168.0.102  Bcast:192.168.0.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::<IP6 'eth0' [IF]>/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:39300 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:32116 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:37458781 (37.4 MB)  TX bytes:4038182 (4.0 MB)
          Interrupt:16 

##### iwconfig ##########################

eth0      no wireless extensions.

lo        no wireless extensions.

##### route #############################

Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
0.0.0.0         192.168.0.1     0.0.0.0         UG    0      0        0 eth0
192.168.0.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     1      0        0 eth0

##### resolv.conf #######################

nameserver 127.0.1.1

##### network managers ##################

Installed:

    NetworkManager

Running:

root       784     1  0 20:55 ?        00:00:00 NetworkManager

##### NetworkManager info ###############

NetworkManager Tool

State: connected (global)

- Device: eth0  [Wired connection 1] -------------------------------------------
  Type:              Wired
  Driver:            tg3
  State:             connected
  Default:           yes
  HW Address:        <MAC 'eth0' [IF]>

  Capabilities:
    Carrier Detect:  yes
    Speed:           100 Mb/s

  Wired Properties
    Carrier:         on

  IPv4 Settings:
    Address:         192.168.0.102
    Prefix:          24 (255.255.255.0)
    Gateway:         192.168.0.1

    DNS:             192.168.0.1

##### NetworkManager.state ##############

[main]
NetworkingEnabled=true
WirelessEnabled=true
WWANEnabled=true
WimaxEnabled=true

##### NetworkManager.conf ###############

[main]
plugins=ifupdown,keyfile,ofono
dns=dnsmasq

[ifupdown]
managed=false

##### NetworkManager profiles ###########

[[/etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/Wi-Fi connection 1]] (600 root)
[connection] id=Wi-Fi connection 1 | type=802-11-wireless
[802-11-wireless] ssid=Subodh
[ipv4] method=auto
[ipv6] method=auto

##### iw reg get ########################

Region: Asia/Kolkata (based on set time zone)

country 00:
    (2402 - 2472 @ 40), (3, 20)
    (2457 - 2482 @ 40), (3, 20), PASSIVE-SCAN, NO-IBSS
    (2474 - 2494 @ 20), (3, 20), NO-OFDM, PASSIVE-SCAN, NO-IBSS
    (5170 - 5250 @ 40), (3, 20), PASSIVE-SCAN, NO-IBSS
    (5735 - 5835 @ 40), (3, 20), PASSIVE-SCAN, NO-IBSS

##### iwlist channels ###################

eth0      no frequency information.

lo        no frequency information.

##### iwlist scan #######################

eth0      Interface doesn't support scanning.

lo        Interface doesn't support scanning.

##### module infos ######################

[wl]
filename:       /lib/modules/3.19.0-32-generic/updates/dkms/wl.ko
license:        MIXED/Proprietary
srcversion:     9A49255BA90267D99664757
depends:        cfg80211
vermagic:       3.19.0-32-generic SMP mod_unload modversions 
parm:           passivemode:int
parm:           wl_txq_thresh:int
parm:           oneonly:int
parm:           piomode:int
parm:           instance_base:int
parm:           nompc:int
parm:           intf_name:string

[b43]
filename:       /lib/modules/3.19.0-32-generic/kernel/drivers/net/wireless/b43/b43.ko
firmware:       b43/ucode9.fw
firmware:       b43/ucode5.fw
firmware:       b43/ucode16_mimo.fw
firmware:       b43/ucode15.fw
firmware:       b43/ucode14.fw
firmware:       b43/ucode13.fw
firmware:       b43/ucode11.fw
license:        GPL
author:         Rafał Miłecki
author:         Gábor Stefanik
author:         Michael Buesch
author:         Stefano Brivio
author:         Martin Langer
description:    Broadcom B43 wireless driver
srcversion:     11BDA0A580599B083FE4F2B
depends:        bcma,ssb,mac80211,cfg80211
intree:         Y
vermagic:       3.19.0-32-generic SMP mod_unload modversions 
signer:         Magrathea: Glacier signing key
sig_key:        0C:8B:EF:E0:C1:E2:89:E4:D8:99:09:26:11:7A:DA:3B:DF:EB:41:9C
sig_hashalgo:   sha512
parm:           bad_frames_preempt:enable(1) / disable(0) Bad Frames Preemption (int)
parm:           fwpostfix:Postfix for the .fw files to load. (string)
parm:           hwpctl:Enable hardware-side power control (default off) (int)
parm:           nohwcrypt:Disable hardware encryption. (int)
parm:           hwtkip:Enable hardware tkip. (int)
parm:           qos:Enable QOS support (default on) (int)
parm:           btcoex:Enable Bluetooth coexistence (default on) (int)
parm:           verbose:Log message verbosity: 0=error, 1=warn, 2=info(default), 3=debug (int)
parm:           pio:Use PIO accesses by default: 0=DMA, 1=PIO (int)
parm:           allhwsupport:Enable support for all hardware (even it if overlaps with the brcmsmac driver) (int)

[bcma]
filename:       /lib/modules/3.19.0-32-generic/kernel/drivers/bcma/bcma.ko
license:        GPL
description:    Broadcom's specific AMBA driver
srcversion:     F17244FFF75F9BDF92327ED
depends:        
intree:         Y
vermagic:       3.19.0-32-generic SMP mod_unload modversions 
signer:         Magrathea: Glacier signing key
sig_key:        0C:8B:EF:E0:C1:E2:89:E4:D8:99:09:26:11:7A:DA:3B:DF:EB:41:9C
sig_hashalgo:   sha512

[mac80211]
filename:       /lib/modules/3.19.0-32-generic/kernel/net/mac80211/mac80211.ko
license:        GPL
description:    IEEE 802.11 subsystem
srcversion:     6AE775D26377F997426A49D
depends:        cfg80211
intree:         Y
vermagic:       3.19.0-32-generic SMP mod_unload modversions 
signer:         Magrathea: Glacier signing key
sig_key:        0C:8B:EF:E0:C1:E2:89:E4:D8:99:09:26:11:7A:DA:3B:DF:EB:41:9C
sig_hashalgo:   sha512
parm:           minstrel_vht_only:Use only VHT rates when VHT is supported by sta. (bool)
parm:           max_nullfunc_tries:Maximum nullfunc tx tries before disconnecting (reason 4). (int)
parm:           max_probe_tries:Maximum probe tries before disconnecting (reason 4). (int)
parm:           beacon_loss_count:Number of beacon intervals before we decide beacon was lost. (int)
parm:           probe_wait_ms:Maximum time(ms) to wait for probe response before disconnecting (reason 4). (int)
parm:           ieee80211_default_rc_algo:Default rate control algorithm for mac80211 to use (charp)

[ssb]
filename:       /lib/modules/3.19.0-32-generic/kernel/drivers/ssb/ssb.ko
license:        GPL
description:    Sonics Silicon Backplane driver
srcversion:     551AE4C23939F7FBED9DA61
depends:        
intree:         Y
vermagic:       3.19.0-32-generic SMP mod_unload modversions 
signer:         Magrathea: Glacier signing key
sig_key:        0C:8B:EF:E0:C1:E2:89:E4:D8:99:09:26:11:7A:DA:3B:DF:EB:41:9C
sig_hashalgo:   sha512

[cfg80211]
filename:       /lib/modules/3.19.0-32-generic/kernel/net/wireless/cfg80211.ko
description:    wireless configuration support
license:        GPL
author:         Johannes Berg
srcversion:     F28307769349A31F4B24FC2
depends:        
intree:         Y
vermagic:       3.19.0-32-generic SMP mod_unload modversions 
signer:         Magrathea: Glacier signing key
sig_key:        0C:8B:EF:E0:C1:E2:89:E4:D8:99:09:26:11:7A:DA:3B:DF:EB:41:9C
sig_hashalgo:   sha512
parm:           ieee80211_regdom:IEEE 802.11 regulatory domain code (charp)
parm:           cfg80211_disable_40mhz_24ghz:Disable 40MHz support in the 2.4GHz band (bool)

##### module parameters #################

[b43]
allhwsupport: 0
bad_frames_preempt: 0
btcoex: 1
hwpctl: 0
hwtkip: 0
nohwcrypt: 0
pio: 0
qos: 1
verbose: 2

[mac80211]
beacon_loss_count: 7
ieee80211_default_rc_algo: minstrel_ht
max_nullfunc_tries: 2
max_probe_tries: 5
minstrel_vht_only: Y
probe_wait_ms: 500

[cfg80211]
cfg80211_disable_40mhz_24ghz: N
ieee80211_regdom: 00

##### /etc/modules ######################

lp
rtc
b43
b43
b43

##### modprobe options ##################

[/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist-ath_pci.conf]
blacklist ath_pci

[/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist-bcm43.conf]
blacklist b43
blacklist b43legacy
blacklist ssb
blacklist bcm43xx
blacklist brcm80211
blacklist brcmfmac
blacklist brcmsmac
blacklist bcma

[/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf]
blacklist evbug
blacklist usbmouse
blacklist usbkbd
blacklist eepro100
blacklist de4x5
blacklist eth1394
blacklist snd_intel8x0m
blacklist snd_aw2
blacklist i2c_i801
blacklist prism54
blacklist bcm43xx
blacklist garmin_gps
blacklist asus_acpi
blacklist snd_pcsp
blacklist pcspkr
blacklist amd76x_edac

[/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist-rare-network.conf]
alias net-pf-3 off
alias net-pf-6 off
alias net-pf-9 off
alias net-pf-11 off
alias net-pf-12 off
alias net-pf-19 off
alias net-pf-21 off
alias net-pf-36 off

[/etc/modprobe.d/iwlwifi.conf]
remove iwlwifi \
(/sbin/lsmod | grep -o -e ^iwlmvm -e ^iwldvm -e ^iwlwifi | xargs /sbin/rmmod) \
&& /sbin/modprobe -r mac80211

[/etc/modprobe.d/mlx4.conf]
softdep mlx4_core post: mlx4_en

##### rc.local ##########################

exit 0

##### pm-utils ##########################

##### udev rules ########################

[/etc/udev/rules.d/70-persistent-net.rules]
# PCI device 0x14e4:0x16b5 (tg3)
SUBSYSTEM=="net", ACTION=="add", DRIVERS=="?*", ATTR{address}=="<MAC 'eth0' [IF]>", ATTR{dev_id}=="0x0", ATTR{type}=="1", KERNEL=="eth*", NAME="eth0"
# PCI device 0x14e4:0x4358 (wl)
SUBSYSTEM=="net", ACTION=="add", DRIVERS=="?*", ATTR{address}=="<MAC address>", ATTR{dev_id}=="0x0", ATTR{type}=="1", KERNEL=="wlan*", NAME="wlan0"

##### dmesg #############################

[   10.043299] bcma: bus0: Found chip with id 43227, rev 0x00 and package 0x08
[   10.043328] bcma: bus0: Core 0 found: ChipCommon (manuf 0x4BF, id 0x800, rev 0x25, class 0x0)
[   10.043348] bcma: bus0: Core 1 found: IEEE 802.11 (manuf 0x4BF, id 0x812, rev 0x1E, class 0x0)
[   10.043384] bcma: bus0: Core 2 found: PCIe (manuf 0x4BF, id 0x820, rev 0x12, class 0x0)
[   10.043402] bcma: bus0: Core 3 found: SDIO Device (manuf 0x4BF, id 0x829, rev 0x07, class 0x0)
[   10.054329] bcma: bus0: Bus registered
[   10.068999] b43-phy0: Broadcom 43227 WLAN found (core revision 30)
[   10.069968] b43-phy0: Found PHY: Analog 9, Type 4 (N), Revision 16
[   10.069978] b43-phy0: Found Radio: Manuf 0x17F, ID 0x2057, Revision 9, Version 1
[   10.279533] b43 bcma0:1: Direct firmware load for b43/ucode30_mimo.fw failed with error -2 (repeated 2 times)
[   10.279586] b43 bcma0:1: Direct firmware load for b43-open/ucode30_mimo.fw failed with error -2 (repeated 2 times)
[   10.279597] b43-phy0 ERROR: Firmware file "b43/ucode30_mimo.fw" not found
[   10.279599] b43-phy0 ERROR: Firmware file "b43-open/ucode30_mimo.fw" not found
[   10.279603] b43-phy0 ERROR: You must go to http://wireless.kernel.org/en/users/Drivers/b43#devicefirmware and download the correct firmware for this driver version. Please carefully read all instructions on this website.
[   10.938573] wl: module license 'MIXED/Proprietary' taints kernel.
[   10.942985] wl: module verification failed: signature and/or  required key missing - tainting kernel
[   14.230775] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): eth0: link is not ready
[   15.760502] tg3 0000:01:00.0 eth0: Link is up at 100 Mbps, full duplex
[   15.760508] tg3 0000:01:00.0 eth0: Flow control is on for TX and on for RX
[   15.760510] tg3 0000:01:00.0 eth0: EEE is disabled
[   15.760534] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_CHANGE): eth0: link becomes ready

########## wireless info END ############
```

Comment: Please follow the guide [at this location](http://askubuntu.com/questions/425155/my-wireless-wifi-connection-does-not-work-what-information-is-needed-to-diagnos) to provide the information that will be needed to help with our problem

Comment: @CharlesGreen Ok let me check but why this is happing in ubuntu ? They dont have any proper fix for this?

Comment: There are many possible reasons, but it is difficult to think of anything constructive to tell you, without knowing some information about your system

Comment: @CharlesGreen Here is the link for Network related information http://paste.ubuntu.com/13209389/

Comment: I *think* you need a driver other than the b43 driver - I will put an answer below which should help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The BCM43227 apparently needs the STA driver, which can be loaded with

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install --reinstall bcmwl-kernel-source
sudo modprobe -r b43 ssb wl brcmfmac brcmsmac bcma
sudo modprobe wl
```

The source for this set of commands is [at this location](https://gist.github.com/glombard/18a7ea331cfc93aff17b)